# Should REST APIs be context independent or dependent?

Tags: web-development, rest

Let's say I have several users and each one has a `user_id` and also `friends`

To access their friends, they should be logged in, so a session will be established with the server.

Should the REST API for their friends be `user/:user_id/friends` or just `friends`

Answer (score 9):

The URL should be the same whether `user` is logged in or not.

The whole point of REST is to be as stateless as possible.  Holding a stateful session so that you can say `friends` instead of `user/:user_id/friends` is not stateless, and the URL pointing to a particular resource should *always be the same.*